# Xamarin.Forms WebView With String HTML Source - Works on iOS but not on UWP (outside the Visual Studio)

Tags: webview, xamarin.forms

Xamarin.Forms PCL application containing several WebViews that are loaded with HTML strings. Runs without any problems on iOS. Runs without any problems within the Visual Studio 2015 environment on UWP. But if I shut Visual Studio down and run the UWP app none of the WebViews appear. What am I doing wrong ? Did I hit a bug ?

Comment: I am not using UWP but do you need to pack an app before you can run it?

Comment: No if you are running on the development machine. It gets automatically installed as an UWP app on that machine every time you build it.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. It is a Xamarin.Forms bug:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=57451

The workaround is to explicitly set a HeightRequest to the Web View.

Comment: That workaround doesn't work for me - it shows sometimes, but sometimes it's blank.